# Printing .2f issue

Tags: java, arrays, printing

So for my output, I'm trying to print

```
System.out.println("CRASH! The game crashed at "+start+" x");
```

However, when I print the variable `start` it comes out as `1.5000000000007x`and I only want it to come out as `1.50x`. I know that I can do `printf` to make it a 2 float number, but when I try to print my sentence as well, the program complies an error. 
I tried :

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",CRASH! The game crashed at "+start+" x");
```

but this didn't work.

I also tried this code in 1 line:

```
System.out.println("CRASH! The game crashed at "); System.out.printf("%.2f",start)
```

but then the value `start` came out on it's own line, which is not what I want.

Any suggestions on how to have both my sentence and .2f var `start` in the same sentence?

Comment: `System.out.printf("CRASH! The game crashed at %.2f x", start);`

Comment: You misplaced a doublequote: `printf("CRASH! The game crashed at %.2f x", start)`

Comment: Thanks you both! Appreeciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you are supposed to use `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("CRASH! The game crashed at %.2fx", start);
```

Note where I put the `start` and `.2f`.

If you want to print it using two `print`s, you can. But you should not use `println`, because that will print an extra new line at the end. Just use `print`:

```
System.out.print("CRASH! The game crashed at "); // here we don't want a new line.
System.out.printf("%.2f",start);
System.out.println("x"); // here we do want a new line.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was EXACTLY how I wanted it to print. Much appreciated. +1

Comment: @PizzaParrot If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark (when the system allows you to)!